# How to pass Android app from foreground to background

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, lifecycle

I'm an Android developer, and I have an annoying problem.

In my onCreate function I establish socket communication, which runs in a thread.

When I lock screen with application in foreground and then unlock the screen, the application goes to onCreate function and it find that another thread and socket are already running, and the "new" onCreate spoils all process.

Otherwise, if I lock screen with app in background, then application doesn't go to onCreate function, and it works fine.

Is there any way to turn application in background when screen lock button is pressed?

First sorry, my english is so poor.
Second, I can't show anything of code because it's not mine but my company.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using services?

Comment: What you need to know is why the activity is beeing recriated, blocking the screen should only pause the activity, not destroy it. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to learn about the activity lifecycle.

Comment: You can either use services as @RocketSpock said or make the thread you are running the socket establishment in static so only one instance can be created and check if its not null create one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in an ASyncTask rather than making your own thread?